# Formatting DataFrame in Pandas - stacking columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am currently working with a DataFrame from a dictionary that I wish to reformat. The dictionary looks like this:

```
transactionDetails = {"paymentStatus":["COMPLETED", "REFUNDED", "COMPLETED"],
                  "address":["123 Fake Street", "123 Example Street", "123 Top Secret"],
                  "item":["Apple", "Banana", "Orange"],
                  "transactionID":["2132123", "54654645", "56754646"],
                  "orderTime":["14:55", "15:10", "23:11"],
                  "email":["example@example.com", "fake@example.com", "notreal@notreal.com"],
                  "refundNotes":[],
                  "notes": []}
```

The dictionary has been written to the DataFrame in the following way:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(transactionDetails, orient='index')
```

This currently outputs the DataFrame as follows:

```
                                     0                   1                    2
paymentStatus            COMPLETED            REFUNDED            COMPLETED
address            123 Fake Street  123 Example Street       123 Top Secret
item                         Apple              Banana               Orange
transactionID              2132123            54654645             56754646
orderTime                    14:55               15:10                23:11
email          example@example.com    fake@example.com  notreal@notreal.com
refundNotes                   None                None                 None
notes                         None                None                 None
```

I would like to present the data vertically in the following way:

```
paymentStatus              COMPLETED
address              123 Fake Street
item                           Apple
transactionID                2132123
orderTime                      14:55
email            example@example.com
refundNotes                     None
notes                           None

paymentStatus              COMPLETED
address           123 Example Street
item                          Banana
transactionID               54654645 
orderTime                      15:10
email               fake@example.com
refundNotes                     None
notes                           None

etc
```

PS: I have tried using `.stack()`, but that resulted in the following output which is not what I'm after:

```
paymentStatus  0              COMPLETED
               1               REFUNDED
               2              COMPLETED
address        0        123 Fake Street
               1     123 Example Street
               2         123 Top Secret
item           0                  Apple
               1                 Banana
               2                 Orange
transactionID  0                2132123
               1               54654645
               2               56754646
orderTime      0                  14:55
               1                  15:10
               2                  23:11
email          0    example@example.com
               1       fake@example.com
               2    notreal@notreal.com
```

Thanks!

Comment: How about `df.stack().sort_index(level=1)`?

Comment: If you want to get rid of that second level, call `reset_index` after. `df.stack().sort_index(level=1).reset_index(level=1, drop=True)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1**
`unstack` + `reset_index` -

```
df.unstack().reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
```

```
paymentStatus              COMPLETED
address              123 Fake Street
item                           Apple
transactionID                2132123
orderTime                      14:55
email            example@example.com
refundNotes                     None
notes                           None
paymentStatus               REFUNDED
address           123 Example Street
item                          Banana
transactionID               54654645
orderTime                      15:10
email               fake@example.com
refundNotes                     None
notes                           None
paymentStatus              COMPLETED
address               123 Top Secret
item                          Orange
transactionID               56754646
orderTime                      23:11
email            notreal@notreal.com
refundNotes                     None
notes                           None
```

---

**Option 2**
`stack` + `sort_index` + `reset_index`

```
df.stack().sort_index(level=1).reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
```

```
paymentStatus              COMPLETED
address              123 Fake Street
item                           Apple
transactionID                2132123
orderTime                      14:55
email            example@example.com
paymentStatus               REFUNDED
address           123 Example Street
item                          Banana
transactionID               54654645
orderTime                      15:10
email               fake@example.com
paymentStatus              COMPLETED
address               123 Top Secret
item                          Orange
transactionID               56754646
orderTime                      23:11
email            notreal@notreal.com
```

Beware that `stack` drops NaN values, so might not be the best option for you.

Comment: seems like only we two here :-)

Comment: @Wen More than enough to provide (hopefully) decent answers for OPs!

Comment: Coldspeed (which I wont bother to write with the hidden ones) is my python hero :) whish I had 10% his expertiese...

Comment: Much appreciated guys, but I don't deserve your praise. I'm just trying to learn, and hopefully help others do the same. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Using `dropna= False`

```
df.stack(dropna=False).swaplevel(0,1).sort_index(level=0)
Out[261]: 
0  address              123 Fake Street
   email            example@example.com
   item                           Apple
   notes                           None
   orderTime                      14:55
   paymentStatus              COMPLETED
   refundNotes                     None
   transactionID                2132123
1  address           123 Example Street
   email               fake@example.com
   item                          Banana
   notes                           None
   orderTime                      15:10
   paymentStatus               REFUNDED
   refundNotes                     None
   transactionID               54654645
2  address               123 Top Secret
   email            notreal@notreal.com
   item                          Orange
   notes                           None
   orderTime                      23:11
   paymentStatus              COMPLETED
   refundNotes                     None
   transactionID               56754646
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

One can use `for` loop to serially add items to a dataframe:

```
indexes = transactionDetails.keys()
dfmade = False
for n in range(3):
    newdict = {}
    for i in indexes:
        if transactionDetails[i]:
            newdict[i]= transactionDetails[i][n]
        else:
            newdict[i] = []
    if dfmade:
        df = pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame.from_dict(newdict, orient='index')])
    else: 
        df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(newdict, orient='index')
        dfmade = True
print(df)
```

Output:

```
                             0
paymentStatus            COMPLETED
transactionID              2132123
item                         Apple
notes                           []
orderTime                    14:55
address            123 Fake Street
refundNotes                     []
email          example@example.com
paymentStatus             REFUNDED
transactionID             54654645
item                        Banana
notes                           []
orderTime                    15:10
address         123 Example Street
refundNotes                     []
email             fake@example.com
paymentStatus            COMPLETED
transactionID             56754646
item                        Orange
notes                           []
orderTime                    23:11
address             123 Top Secret
refundNotes                     []
email          notreal@notreal.com
```